# Displaying movements of moving object in cartodb?

Tags: carto, gps

I have few GPS tracks with lat long and timestamp. I want to present them on a map and to show how the movement took place using the time series location values (X,Y,T). I searched a lot but could not find any suitable map visualization technique for moving objects. Cartodb offers visualization on the web with an appealing presentation.

I was wondering if it can be done in Cartodb?

I am looking to develop something like this-
http://here.com/livingcities/
Click on the metro cities on the webpage (the link provided above) and you can see the visualization.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can do with your data, probably the most straight forward is to import it and then use the timestamp to create a Torque wizard.

Also you can follow our tutorial to create lines from the points of your gps http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/gps_track.html

Answer (score 1):

Besides CartoDB, the OpenStreetMap community made a few tools for making a video out of a set of GPS tracks.

The original on was "[Party Render](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Party_render)" which will produce a video [like this one for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DTI3HVz5BQ). It's a bunch of old python scripts.

Since then we've seen a been a bunch of [Party render#Alternatives](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Party_render#Alternatives)

We used to use GPS a lot during "Mapping Parties" (These days less so), so these tools were used to make funky videos showing where all the mappers had headed out that day. The tools are typically designed to cope with a number of GPS traces ~between 5 and 25 all moving at the same time. So fewer moving points than in the example you linked. That example reminds me of [this London Bike Hire animation](http://oobrien.com/2011/02/boris-bikes-flow-video-now-with-better-curves/) (although that's not using GPS traces)